# How to pass dynamic $scope via $scope.extend to leaflet center and marker

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

current situation:
[image]

I've got an api/json-string with geolocation data for an airplane take off and landing position (each one lat & lng) as you can see in the top right corner of the console.

And I've got a working leaflet directive, if I use example data or hard coded lat & lng numbers.

But I want to do the following:
1) Add Center to the takeoff-location
2) Draw a marker on the takeoff-location
3) Draw a marker on the landing-location

Problem:
If I use $scope or even variables (var = data.jsonvar) the leaflet container stays grey with the seen error messages.

Question:
How can I draw those markers an set the center to the data, the api provides?

**View:**

```
<leaflet width="100%" height="500px" markers="markers" center="centerMap"></leaflet>
```

**Controller:**

```
showTrackDetails = function (trackId) {

        // Holt die Informationen zum Flug und öffnet im Success-Fall das Modal mit den Informationen
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: xxx
            data: {
                userId: $localStorage.currentUser,
                userApikey: $localStorage.apiKey,
                func: 'trackData',
                trackId: trackId
            },
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        })
            .success(function (data) {

                /* ==== MARKER START/ZIEL ==== */

                // Holt Marker-Positionen aus der JSON-Antwort
                $scope.markerTakeoffLat = data.markerTakeoffLat;
                $scope.markerTakeoffLng = data.markerTakeoffLng;

                $scope.markerLandingLat = data.markerLandingLat;
                $scope.markerLandingLng = data.markerLandingLng;

                // Setzt den MAP-Fokus auf den Startflughafen
                angular.extend($scope, {
                    centerMap: {
                        //lat: 51.505,
                        //lng: -0.09,
                        lat: $scope.markerTakeoffLat,
                        lng: $scope.markerTakeoffLng,
                        zoom: 8
                    },
                    markers: {}
                });

                // Setzt die beiden Marker in die Map
                angular.extend($scope, {
                    markers: {
                        markerTakeoff: {
                            //lat: 51.505,
                            //lng: -0.09,
                            lat: $scope.markerTakeoffLat,
                            lng: $scope.markerTakeoffLng,
                            //message: "I'm a static marker",
                            draggable: false
                        },
                        markerLanding: {
                            //lat: 51,
                            //lng: 0,
                            lat: $scope.markerLandingLat,
                            lng: $scope.markerLandingLng,
                            focus: true,
                            //message: "Hey, drag me if you want",
                            draggable: false
                        }
                    }
                });

            }); // Ende .success

    };

    // onClickEvent (Show Track in Map-Modal)
    $scope.showTrackDetails = function(trackId){
        showTrackDetails(trackId);
    };
```

**Sample JSON/API-Output for testing:**

```
{"trackId":"14","logbookid":"0","public":"1","waypoints":"1443345806571|51.4034139|6.9406291|244|66|29;1443345915427|51.4276257|6.9685559|531|335|41.5;1443346042404|51.4655081|6.9116662|663|340|42;1443346154427|51.5066894|6.9035492|675|4|29.75;1443346269492|51.5411881|6.9023895|1026|352|34.5;1443346385475|51.578387|6.8949114|1280|358|39.25;1443346482089|51.6139763|6.8965465|1373|3|41.752994537353516;1443346603144|51.6605393|6.8944484|1418|351|45.002777099609375;1443346705498|51.7009922|6.8874368|1410|357|43.502872467041016;1443346789493|51.7342175|6.8843293|1401|355|44.75279235839844;1443346861445|51.7624781|6.8817369|1396|357|44.00284194946289;1443346951496|51.7979765|6.8780592|1394|356|43.502872467041016;1443347014911|51.8226123|6.8795048|1402|4|44.25282287597656;1443347075854|51.8465136|6.8769062|1400|352|43.502872467041016;1443347193422|51.8928339|6.8720631|1391|357|43.252891540527344;1443347253415|51.9157133|6.8723428|1384|2|42.5029411315918;1443347313414|51.9382442|6.8763271|1372|9|42.252960205078125;1443347390479|51.9652399|6.8872517|1369|17|40.50308609008789;1443347466402|51.9799349|6.9206835|1364|68|39.753143310546875;1443347559538|51.9964971|6.969501|1279|55|39.753143310546875;1443347643471|52.0130553|7.0108174|1253|58|39.753143310546875;1443347703747|52.0248678|7.0409258|1247|60|40.00312423706055;1443347763805|52.0328008|7.0729704|1236|73|40.00312423706055;1443347822704|52.0392404|7.1067839|1221|69|40.5;1443347882706|52.0459711|7.140825|1190|73|41.5;1443347943793|52.0523324|7.1763928|1173|72|40.75;1443348003782|52.0594154|7.2107625|1150|74|44.5;1443348063936|52.0698866|7.2416742|1094|54|42.75;1443348132969|52.0867675|7.2741101|1005|52|41.5;1443348197498|52.1048507|7.2987282|876|36|42.5;1443348282430|52.1271505|7.3378987|685|53|43.75;1443348356500|52.1425242|7.3765305|591|61|44;1443348486440|52.1655872|7.4502212|452|67|42.75;1443348574543|52.1799935|7.5014238|482|59|42.75;1443348679438|52.1982497|7.5586922|568|77|43.75;1443348780628|52.2076796|7.6216782|577|75|42.75;1443348852270|52.2156638|7.6652717|536|74|42.75;1443348922504|52.2217186|7.7080782|523|74|41.75;1443348986442|52.2330283|7.7440682|519|55|43.25;1443349074264|52.2502821|7.7910733|485|62|42.5;1443349178209|52.261576|7.8540636|476|80|43;1443349287101|52.2823998|7.8995987|368|57|41;1443349397446|52.2866062|7.9615992|141|91|31;","lfzid":"4","savedate":"2015-09-27 12:26:36","markerTakeoffLat":"51.4034139","markerTakeoffLng":"6.9406291","markerLandingLat":"52.2866062","markerLandingLng":"7.9615992"}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing strings for `lat` and `lng` because your JSON response defines these properties as strings instead of numeric. You need to use numeric latitude and longitude.

An easy fix is to coerce the data to numeric using `+` when you assign to the scope, like this:

```
            $scope.markerTakeoffLat = +data.markerTakeoffLat;
            $scope.markerTakeoffLng = +data.markerTakeoffLng;

            $scope.markerLandingLat = +data.markerLandingLat;
            $scope.markerLandingLng = +data.markerLandingLng;
```

Here is an except from [a working JS Fiddle with your sample data](http://jsfiddle.net/cj4pe5um/):

```
  $scope.addMarkers = function() {
                angular.extend($scope, {
                    markers: {
                        markerTakeoff: {
                            lat: +data.markerTakeoffLat,
                            lng: +data.markerTakeoffLng,
                            message: "I'm a static marker",
                            draggable: false
                        }
                    }
                });
  };
```

Comment: This seems to actually be caused by a bug or "feature" in the angular-leaflet plugin because I didn't have any problems using strings for `lat` and `lng` in Leaflet: http://jsfiddle.net/pvobnf3z/ - although if you are using decimal latitude and longitude, they should probably be numeric anyway